# Element added to DOM but doesn't display on screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Basically my problem is that when i add an element from the javascript (using jquery) the element that i added shows up in the web inspector but doesn't display in the browser at all.

What i am trying to do is simulate something i liked about google+ when it first came out, which is when you want to the user to enter a list of item, you provide them with one text field and once they start to add something to that text field then instantly after the first character is typed a new text field with appear under that.  So I'm my code, i have the user entering a series of goals they want to achieve, i provide them with a single text field (or multiple if the user is editing the list they previously made) and once the last text field has data then it will programmatically create a new text field.

HTML:

```
<div class="field-group clickToAddGroup">
  <label>Goals: </label>
  <div class="input">
    <input type="text" name="goals" value="Goal1">
    <input type="text" name="goals" value="Goal2">
    <input type="text" name="goals" value="Goal3">
    <input type="text" name="goals" value="Goal4">
    <input type="text" name="goals" placeholder="Type to add Goal" class="clickToAdd">
  </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(".clickToAdd").live('keyup',function(){
    console.log("key up triggered");
    if( $(this).val() != '' )
    {
        console.log("cloning in process");

        var theClone = $(this).clone().val('');    // Set the new element to null
        theClone.appendTo( $(this).parent() ); // Clone Parent
        $(this).removeClass('clickToAdd');     // Remove the click to add class

        console.log("clone complete");
    }
    console.log("key up finished");
    console.log("----");
});

$('.clickToAddGroup input').live('blur', function(){
    if( $(this).val() == '' && !$(this).hasClass('clickToAdd') )
        $(this).remove();
});
```

Now the code above actually works, however when the page first loads when i click (or tab to) the last text field (one that has the clickToAdd class) and begin typing, i see in the web inspector that the javascript ran correctly and created the new field and placed it where it should, but i don't actually see it on the screen.  But when i take the content that i had just wrote in the text field, delete it, and lose focus (triggering 'blur') the text field is deleted and then i can see the textfield that was shown.  From this point on when i add content to the last field (one with the clickToAdd class) it works 100% perfectly, it adds the element and is visible via both the web inspector AND is displayed on screen.

Edit:  I copied the code to jsfiddle (included css i am using as well) and tried it there and it happens to work perfectly as intended without the issue i am having.  http://jsfiddle.net/qz2QK/2/

Edit 2: Added "var" to the line "var theClone = $(this).clone().val('');" so that its not implicitly a global variable.

Comment: beware implicitly global variables.

Comment: I assume `<div class="input">` should really be `<div class="clickToAddGroup">`

Comment: Marc: Sorry i didn't copy the whole structure ( if you look above you can see the full html of that )

Comment: I copied your code and tested it here, it all works for me. Try emptying your cache.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? What is your dev environment (browser, etc)? Also, great job asking, +1 - helps so much to provide as much info as you did.

Comment: Alan: Yea i copied my code to JSFiddle and tested it there, and its working 100%.  I'm stumped why its not working for me :/

Comment: User1090190:  It's running locally on my machine, i have an apache web server setup for my development (i've never had issues with that), i'm using jQuery v1.6.2, testing in Safari (haven't looked at other browsers yet).

Comment: Inspect the script as loaded by your browser. Make sure it's 100% the same as the one you know works.

Comment: Well, i've figured out the issue.  somehow the styling for ".field-group label" has the css element "float: left;" in it, when i remove that, it works perfectly for me.  Strange though how it work in JSFiddle with that float:left being there.  Anyways thanks for all the input, it was greatly appreciated.